# What does `${1+/$1}` mean in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I was reading a Bash script with this line:

```
FOO=${1+/$1}
```

What does this line do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/` makes it look slightly more confusing than it is, but this is just an example of `${foo+bar}`, which expands to `bar` if `$foo` is set.

In this case, the variable is `$1`, the first positional parameter passed to the script or function.

```
example () {
  echo "${1+/$1}"
}

example     # outputs nothing
example ''  # outputs "/"
example foo # outputs "/foo"
```

There is a table that summarises these [parameter expansions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) in the spec. The rules for `${parameter+word}` are:

- Set and Not Null: substitute `word`
- Set But Null: substitute `word`
- Unset: substitute null

So to answer your question directly, `FOO=${1+/$1}` assigns `/$1` to `FOO` is `$1` is set, otherwise `FOO` is set to null (an empty string).